# HTML, HEAD, BODY css issue

Tags: html, css, styling, document-body, laravel-4.2

I currently have an issue with my page, where the contents of the page are not filling 100% of the screen. (Laravel 4.2)
[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBj7O.png)

My code is as follows

**master.blade.php**

HTML/Javscript code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials">
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">
    <meta name="author" content="John Doe">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Student Timetable</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="/images/calander.ico">

    <script src="/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container script" style="display:none">
        @include('layouts.banner')
        @include('layouts.navigation')
    <div class="content">
        dasda
          
           @include('layouts.messages')
           @yield('content')
    </div>  
</div>
</body>
@yield('modal')
@yield('javascript')
<script type="text/javascript" id="cookiebanner" src="http://cookiebanner.eu/js/cookiebanner.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.script').attr('style', 'block');

        });
</script>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```css
html {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    height:100%;
}

.navigation {
  width:150px;
}

.container {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.content {
  background-color:#000000;
  top:-100px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

body {
    background: #F0EDED;
}
```

I cannot figure out what the issue is. If anybody has any suggestions that would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting default margins and paddings by adding this to css:

```
*{
   maring:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

And also for calculating width use vw units:

```
width:100vw;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the css for body tag in this way:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #F0EDED;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant use

```css
html {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    height:100%;
}
```

use:
astrick (*) insted of html

Answer (score 0):

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of some explanation. Covering why and how is important, and will keep your answers from ending up in the review queues.